# Can Travis create a directory under / without sudo for the new infrastructure?

Tags: travis-ci

For the CI testing of https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs we don't need sudo, except that we need a writeable and cached directory `/nix`.

Is it possible to create that directory before the test scripts start? Then we would be able to use the new architecture and caching, which would mean a lot less downloading.